# Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: DB::$c

Tags: php

I am using https://github.com/Xeoncross/DByte this PDO wrapper in my code 
This site was working fine until last day, Now i can a see an error message in the site which is following.

```
Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: DB::$c in 
/home/NAME/public_html/TEST/inc/config.php on line 16
```

My code with line 16 is

```
require('DB.php');

$pdo = new PDO(
'mysql:dbname=DBNAME;host=localhost',
'DBUSER',
'MYPASSWORD',
 array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
 )
 );
 DB::$c = $pdo;
 ?>
```

What will be the issue in line DB::$c = $pdo; i am with this from the after noon.

Comment: Your class `DB ` doesn't have static property $c...

Comment: Well, the error message is crystal clear, isn't it? `$c` is _not_ a static property if that class. I suggest you take a look into the class implementation. Either it has changed (an upgrade maybe?) or because of whatever circumstance another class `DB` is suddenly used (maybe some other package installed?).

Comment: how can i add `$c` as static poperty. This was working fine i didn't make any updates its downloaded and included in my app

Comment: `use \DByte\DB;` ?

Comment: i also tried it. My class is some different form their actual one This was working fine before